# The derivative of piecewise linear function that vanishes at every other dyadic rational

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $D_n = \{\frac{k}{2^n}:0 \leq k \leq 2^n\}$ Define function $F_n(x) = 0$ when $x \in D_{n-1}$ and it is piecewise linearly interpolated between consecutive points of $D_n$ (which means to define the value at any point between two consecutive points of $D_n$ just join the function values at those two points  by a straight line). Then I see in a book to claim the following

$$\|F_n'\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{2 \|F_n\|_{\infty}}{2^{-n}}$$

I am not understanding why 2 is required in the RHS quantity. here $\|.\|_{\infty}$ stands for the usual sup norm in $[0,1]$.

NOTE: This is the levi construction of Brownian motion which is constructed in $[0,1]$ as $B(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n(t)$

Comment: What is the value of $F_n$ at the point $1/2^{n+1}$?

Comment: @uniquesolution: I said already it is linearly interpolated between $0$ and $1/2^{n}$. So, value at the point you mentioned will be that linear interpolation value

Comment: You actually did not say that. Your function is not well defined. You only wrote the $x$ values -- these are the points of $D_n$. I don't see any points in the plane to interpolate between. Can you please define more accurately your function? As it is written now, $F_n\equiv 0$ is also an "interpolated" function.

Comment: @uniquesolution: now wrote it properly.

Comment: **Now** this appears in your question. Then $\|F'_n\|_\infty$ is the constant value $\alpha$ of $F'_n$ on some interval $(a,b)$ with $a$ in $D_{n-1}$ and $b=a\pm1/2^n$, which implies that $F_n(b)=\pm\alpha/2^n$ hence $\alpha\leqslant2^n\|F_n\|_\infty$. That is, the desired inequality, with no factor $2$. Perhaps $F_n$ uses $D_n$ and $D_{n+1}$ instead of $D_{n-1}$ and $D_n$.